# PermissionError: [Errno 13] in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just starting to learn some Python and I'm having an issue as stated below:

```py
a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test', encoding='utf-8')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test', encoding='utf-8')
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'E:\\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\\Test\
```

Seems to be a file permission error, if any one can shine some light it would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE: not sure how Python and Windows files work but I'm logged in to Windows as Admin and the folder has admin permissions.**

I have tried changing `.exe` properties to run as Admin.

Comment: Is `Test` a file or a folder?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson It's definitely a folder, as we can see in the end of the error line. Make that an answer.

Comment: Test is a folder, the Document im following reads i can open a text doc using the following syntax a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test\a.txt', encoding='utf-8') using this syntax aswell as a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test', encoding='utf-8') gives me the same error.

Comment: By the way, remember to use raw strings for Windows pathnames, or you'll get bitten badly if a subfolder name should happen to start with `n` or `b` or any other letter that can be part of an escape sequence...

Comment: ok so the file was on a flash drive and the flash driver was FAT32 and my HD is NTFS so it was format conflicts >< doing it locally works fine, thanks guys

Comment: sorry raw strings lol ??

Comment: @BenniMcBeno raw strings are strings prefixed with r, thus: r'C:\Temp' is equivalent to 'C:\\Temp' the first is referred to as a raw string, so no escaping characters is necessary.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

When doing;

```
a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test', encoding='utf-8')
```

...you're trying to open a *directory* as a file, which may (and on most non UNIX file systems will) fail.

Your other example though;

```
a_file = open('E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test\a.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

should work well if you just have the permission on `a.txt`. You may want to use a raw (`r`-prefixed) string though, to make sure your path does not contain any escape characters like `\n` that will be translated to special characters.

```
a_file = open(r'E:\Python Win7-64-AMD 3.3\Test\a.txt', encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 41):

For me, I was writing to a file that is opened in Excel.

Answer (score 3):

For me, I got this error when I was trying to write a file to a folder and wanted to make sure the folder existed. I accidentally used:

```py
path = Path("path/to/my/file.txt")
path.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
with open(path, "w") as file:
    ...
```

but the second line means "make a *directory* at *this* exact path (and make its parents too, without throwing errors for them existing already)". The third line then throws a `PermissionError`, because you can't use `open()` on a *directory* path, of course! The second line should have been:

```py
path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem when I accidentally tried running my python module through the command prompt while my working directory was `C:\Windows\System32` instead of the usual directory from which I run my python module