# Permission Error: Using Image.open

Tags: python, list, numpy, python-imaging-library

I am using PIL for Image.open

The following is my Image path:

```
loc = "./data/Flicker8k_reshaped"
```

When I try to open an image file in this path, with the following usage it opens an image.

```
Image.open(loc + "/" + train_filenames[0]) # Opens an image 
np.array(Image.open(loc + "/" + train_filenames[0])) # converts that into numpy array
```

train_filenames is the list which contains the file names of the images which I need to vectorize using numpy array.

But when I try to run it in a loop and list comprehension,

```
train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in train_filenames])
```

I get the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-90eaea1b75ca> in <module>()
----> 1 train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in train_filenames])
      2 test = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in test_filenames])
      3 val = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in val_filenames])
      4 
      5 print(train.shape)

<ipython-input-35-90eaea1b75ca> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 train = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in train_filenames])
      2 test = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in test_filenames])
      3 val = np.array([np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)) for fname in val_filenames])
      4 
      5 print(train.shape)

C:\Anaconda\envs\tensorflow-cpu\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)
   2541 
   2542     if filename:
-> 2543         fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
   2544         exclusive_fp = True
   2545
```

Looks like

> builtins.open(filename, "rb")

I picked some 5 filenames and saved it in a different list and ran the above statement and ran the code over the loop. It worked too. I think the " error message here is misleading. "

Comment: Do you have permissions to open the files in that directory?

Comment: Yes I do. That's how I could open it outside the loop

Comment: It makes no sense that when the open statement is inside a loop you get a permission error and outside the loop you don't.  Outside the loop you open one file.  Inside the loop you open several files.  If you lack permission to open even one of them, you will get an error.  Have you checked all the files?

Comment: Yes. I have full permission over the files. I mean the whole directory.

Comment: I picked some 5 filenames and saved it in a different list and ran the above statement and ran the code over the loop. It worked too. I think the " error message here is misleading. "

Comment: It's clearly one specific file/filename that's causing your problem. You just nee to figure out which is the rotten apple

Comment: omg. that was an empty line :-(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It could just be that one of the file names in `train_filenames` is invalid (even though `train_filenames[0]` obviously is valid). Just for debugging purposes (you can put it back later once it's working), unpack the list comprehension you're using to open your images into a `for` loop and add a `print` statement:

```
images = []
for fname in train_filenames:
    print(loc+"/"+fname)
    images.append(np.array(Image.open(loc+"/"+fname)))
train = np.array(images)
```

The last filename that prints out before you get an exception will be the problem one. Apparently one of the things that can cause `PermissionError` on Windows is if you try to [open a directory as a file...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13207548/425458)

Alternatively, if the loop breaks after the first file, then you know you have a weirder/harder to fix problem on your hands.

Comment: it was an empty line. no filename was there. But the error message was kinda misleading

Comment: That'd do it. Annoyingly, the same problem raises a different exception (`FileNotFoundError`) on Unix/Mac. That one's a bit more straightforward

Comment: if it was FileNotFound, It would have made little bit explicit sense. Thank you