# How to add multiple columns and assigning into new column name by using function in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame which has 50 columns. I would like to sum 10 columns and store the same into new column name (called savings to be created). I have 10 files, hence want to use function and apply the same to all the files.

Right now I am using iloc and it's working fine. I don't know how to bring this into a function?

my dataframe name called df.

```
df['savings'] = df.iloc[:,11:27].sum(axis = 1).round(2)
```

I want to use function and checked the below. But it is not working

```
def saving(x):
    x = df.iloc[:,11:27].sum(axis = 1).round(2)
    return(x)

df['savings] = df.applymap(x)
```

This is not working. Any suggestion. I have 10 different files and want to do the same sum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need pass `DataFrame` to `function`:

```
def saving(x):
    x['savings'] = x.iloc[:,11:27].sum(axis = 1).round(2)
    return x
```

If need apply function to `DataFrame` use [`DataFrame.pipe`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html):

```
df = df.pipe(saving)
```

Or:

```
df = saving(df)
```

Loop by files, create `DataFrame`s and apply function if need apply function to multiple DataFrames:

```
import glob

for f in glob.glob('files/*.csv'):
    df = pd.read_csv(f).pipe(saving)
    print (df)
```

Comment: def saving(x):
    x['sav'] = x.iloc[:,11:27].sum(axis = 1).round(2)
    return x

df['sav'] = df.apply(saving)  .. It's not working.. Getting error message""'int' object has no attribute 'iloc'", 'occurred at index nohhold')"

Comment: @sdh2000 - no, you need `df = df.pipe(saving)` instead `df['sav'] = df.apply(saving) `

Comment: def saving(x):
    x['savings'] = x.iloc[:,11:27].sum(axis = 1).round(2)
    return x

df= df.pipe(saving) I am getting error "Permission denied"

Comment: @sdh2000 - and `df = saving(df)` ?

Comment: @sdh2000 - hmmm, not problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083806/permissionerror-permission-denied-to-reading-csv-file-in-python) ?

Comment: it's not working.. what would be the reason.. again getting permission denied

Comment: @sdh2000 What is full error ? There is no permission denied for some file?

Comment: PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: @sdh2000 - no idea what should be problem, if not problem with files.

Comment: is there any other method to this function?

Comment: @sdh2000 - Is possible see your full script?

Comment: It' s working now. I just restarted by the jupyter notebook. But the all values in the savings becomes 0. Sum is not working in the function.

Comment: its coming 0.0... Now I applied lamda  and getting error "("<lambda>() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'", 'occurred at index regio')"

Comment: @sdh2000 - oops, typo, need `x.iloc[:,11:27].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='coerce')).sum(axis=1)`