# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: can't save csv file

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, csv, export-to-csv

I was trying to convert a data frame to a CSV file using the to_csv() function. But I am getting the error "PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'lamda0.45.csv'".
My code is as below:

```
agent_df.to_csv("lamda{}.csv".format(lamda),sep='\t',  encoding='utf-8')
```

agent_df is my data frame and I need to identify a CSV file with a corresponding lambda value when used in a loop.
NB: I am trying to save the file in the same folder as my program codes.
Also, I don't have the same file open anywhere as suggested in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083806/permissionerror-permission-denied-to-reading-csv-file-in-python).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: Permission denied to reading CSV File in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083806/permissionerror-permission-denied-to-reading-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: All those answers specify an already opened file of the same name. But I don't have any file open and hence it is confusing.

Comment: Does the file already exist in your program directory?

Comment: what is your current working directory? Are you out-of-space? Is it a windows protected folder?

Comment: @jaintj95 The file is not being created.

Comment: @anurag No, it's not a protected folder and I have plenty of space.

Comment: try to save your file with a hardcoded name once.

Comment: So, I was using spyder and it didn't work. But when I switched to jupyter notebook, the file is being saved and there is no permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

This error usually occurs when the csv file you're trying to save is already open. Check if it is closed before running the `pd.to_csv`

Comment: I don't have a CSV file of the same name open anywhere.

Comment: @NamithaTresaJoppan  can you print what `lamda` is?

Comment: lamda is 0.45. It's a parameter value.

Comment: Hi, thank you for trying to help. When I switched to jupyter notebook, this is working fine. Earlier I was using it in spyder.