# How to append dataframes in single dataframe and then write those dataframes in new csv files in a different folder?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to to append dataframes in single dataframe and then write those dataframes in new csv files in a different folder. Could any one please check the code and suggest a better answer?

Given the function below:

```
def clean_files(input_folder_path, output_folder_path):
        #get the ist of all csv files in the given folder
        csv_list = [file for file in os.listdir(input_folder_path) if file.endswith('.csv')]
        
        #initialize an empty list to store the individual dataframe
        df =[]
        
        #loop through each csv file, clean the first five rows and create a dataframe
        for file in csv_list:
            file_path = os.path.join(input_folder_path,file)

        #read the csv file into a dataframe
        for i, file in enumerate(csv_list):
            df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_folder_path}/{file}",skiprows = 5,low_memory=False)
         
        #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
        for i, frame in enumerate(df):
            cleaned_df = pd.concat(frame[i])
        
        print(cleaned_df)

        #display the cleaned dataframes
        #for i, df in enumerate(cleaned_df):
           # print(f"df{i+1}:\n{df}\n")
        
        #save the cleaned dataframe to a new csv file in the output folder
        output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"cleaned_{file}")
        df.to_csv(output_folder_path, index=False)
        
        #append the cleaned dataframe to the list
        cleaned_df.append(df)
        return cleaned_df
```

pasted the code but its not able to append the cleaned dataframe to the list

Comment: The first error I would like to point is the creation of an empty list with `df = []` and then in the `for loop` you overwrite this variable with `df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_folder_path}/{file}",skiprows = 5,low_memory=False)` , deleting the list.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
import glob, os

def clean_files(input_folder_path, output_folder_path):
    
        #get the list of all csv files in the given folder
        csv_list =  glob.glob(f'{input_folder_path}/*.csv')

        #read the csv file into a  list of dataframes
        dfs = [pd.read_csv(file, skiprows = 5,low_memory=False) for file in csv_list]
         
        #create big one DataFrame
        cleaned_df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
        print(cleaned_df)

        #display the cleaned dataframes
        #for df in dfs:
           # print(df)
        
        #name of new file
        f = 'output_file.csv'

        #save the cleaned dataframe to a new csv file in the output folder
        output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"cleaned_{f}")
        cleaned_df.to_csv(output_folder_path, index=False)
        
        #if need only write to file omit return cleaned_df
        #return cleaned_df
```

If need clead DataFrames and write to new output path use:

```
def clean_files(input_folder_path, output_folder_path):
    
        #if not exist ouput path create it
        if not os.path.exists(output_folder_path):
            os.makedirs(output_folder_path)
    
        #get the list of all csv files in the given folder

        for file in os.listdir(input_folder_path):
            if file.endswith('.csv'):
                
                #create DataFrame
                df = pd.read_csv(f"{input_folder_path}/{file}",
                                 skiprows = 5,low_memory=False)
                
                #cleaning DataFrame
                #....
                #....
                
                #save the dataframe to a new csv file in the output folder
                output_folder_path = os.path.join(output_folder_path, f"cleaned_{file}")
                df.to_csv(output_folder_path, index=False)
        
        #if need only write to file omit return cleaned_df
        #return cleaned_df
```

Comment: Thanks Mate; however, i need each cleaned dataframe to be copied to a new csv file. Your suggestion has created a one big merged csv file. I am looking for cleaned individual files.

Comment: @pankajsonawane - So need copy file from `input_folder_path` to `output_folder_path` ? Or missing part in code for clean DataFrames?

Comment: The files from input folder needs to cleaned and then copied to output folder with a name having prefix of clean.

Comment: @pankajsonawane - answer was edited, can you test?

Comment: your code just changed the name of the file which had only 1 cleaned csv. I needed that for all csvs from input folder eg : Input folder : file1, file 2, file3 ... I need the files to be cleaned and then copy the cleaned files to output folder : file1_clean, file2_clean,file3_clean

Comment: i am not able to add the code block in the comment ... Can you please suggest i am new to this stackoverflow... I can copy the code which i am testing.

Comment: @pankajsonawane - second part of my code not working? It should be.

Comment: i ran your code without editing . It created only 1 file and threw this error :Exception has occurred: OSError
Cannot save file into a non-existent directory:

Comment: @pankajsonawane - add code `f not exist ouput path create it` to second paragraph

Comment: SOrry mate didnt get that.. Can you elaborate after which block ??

Comment: @pankajsonawane - second block, 4. row

Comment: getting this error:  Exception has occurred: PermissionError
[Errno 13] Permission denied

Comment: @pankajsonawane - Problem is permissions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50083806/permissionerror-permission-denied-to-reading-csv-file-in-python