# Host a flask web GUI using amazon EC2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2

I was trying to host a `flask` based web GUI using `AWS EC2 instance`. But it failed to host the HTML page saying an error

> '''PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied'''

I have given port `80` and `22` inbound access, But it didn't solve my problem. My code has to call `google gensim model`, So I have uploaded the model and some dictionary which will be called while the code is running. I have uploaded the index web page as well. I have checked the code for error, But the code as such contains no error. But the permission denied is the problem.

Any help in this regard would be largely appreciated.

Comment: Please try to explain your question such as what kind of `OS`, what kind of server such as `apache2` or any other and what have you tried till now.

Comment: I chosed Amazon Linux 2 AMI (HVM), SSD Volume Type in Amazon EC2 instance.

Comment: Please flow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python if it solve your problem