# Why am I getting 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied' when tried opening an excel file?

Tags: python

Hello I'm trying to access an excel file within python. I'm using this code we learned in class:

```
with open("file_name") as csv_file:
    csv_reader =csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

and each time I run it I get the same error

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'file_name'
```

is there any code that I could run that would allow the command shell to read the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python)

Comment: You are probably supposed to replace `"file_name"` with the actual name and or path of your file.

Comment: Remove the quotation marks from "file_name""

Comment: Either the file path is wrong or the user doesn't have read permission on the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `file_name` with the **correct path and file name**, i.e.:

```
import csv
with open("/home/user/path/to/file.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

For windows will look like:

```
import csv
with open("c:\\path\\to\\file.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
```

Comment: So the new code is (with the file name): 
import os, csv

os.mkdir('AI-Radar.csv')
with open("c:\\path\\to\\AI-Radar.csv") as csv_file:
 csv_reader =csv.DictReader(csv_file

but now it's saying that AI-Radar.csv is not in the directory and that's why I added the os.mkdir, but it still won't add it to the directory @Pedro Lobito

Comment: I also have no clue how to edit my comments to make then look nice in the gray box so any tips for that would be amazing @pedro

Comment: You cannot edit comments after 5 minutes. Make sure the path is correct and you should be good to go.

Comment: I'm going to be honest I don't know what that means lol how do I change it to real path. is a path the AI-Radar.csv?