# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'saves'

Tags: python

I would like to open a folder with Pycharm but I get an error every time I try ...

I just execute the command:

saves = open ("saves")

I've tried starting it as an administrator but it didn't work

I've tried changing the folder permissions and it didn't work either

I would like help thanks!

Comment: you can't open a folder, you can open a file in a folder though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PermissionError: \[Errno 13\] in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python)