# error permission acces denied when load image for classification with keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, file-upload, image-classification

How can i load image from keras with local image ? can i ? because im getting error permission access denied?
im trying to classification image with tensorflow from local jupyter notebook.

```
import numpy as np
from keras.preprocessing import image
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg


img = image.load_img(os.getcwd()+'/tmp/test/british_cat/', target_size=(150,150))
imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)

images = np.vstack([x])
classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
# model.summary()
print(classes[0:10])
  

if classes[0][0]==1:
    print('British Cat')
elif classes[0][1]==1:
    print('Love Bird')
elif classes[0][2]==1:
    print('Koi Fish')
else:
    print('error')
```

the error is :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-49-7b705ffefd08> in <module>
      6 
      7 
----> 8 img = image.load_img(os.getcwd()+'/tmp/test/british_cat/', target_size=(150,150))
      9 imgplot = plt.imshow(img)
     10 x = image.img_to_array(img)

~\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\preprocessing\image.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    298       ValueError: if interpolation method is not supported.
    299   """
--> 300   return image.load_img(path, grayscale=grayscale, color_mode=color_mode,
    301                         target_size=target_size, interpolation=interpolation)
    302 

~\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py in load_img(path, grayscale, color_mode, target_size, interpolation)
    111         raise ImportError('Could not import PIL.Image. '
    112                           'The use of `load_img` requires PIL.')
--> 113     with open(path, 'rb') as f:
    114         img = pil_image.open(io.BytesIO(f.read()))
    115         if color_mode == 'grayscale':

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\Users\\AZHAR IE\\Documents\\project\\webscraping google\\Google-Image-Scraper-master/tmp/test/british_cat/
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python

Answer (score 1):

You can get the image names by "os.listdir" then you can load images one by one using for loop.

```
folder= "./tmp/test/british_cat/"
image_names=os.listdir(folder)
for filename in image_names:
    img = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(folder+filename, target_size=(150, 150))
          
    x=image.img_to_array(img)
    x=np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    images = np.vstack([x])
      
    classes = model.predict(images, batch_size=10)
```