# PermissionError when opening a flle (working on Mac but not PC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-watchdog

I'm trying to monitor a folder with Python3.
My program below (please bear with my messy code...) works perfectly fine on Mac, but it acts weird on PC.
It works as expected when I put the first image into the folder, but then I get `PermissionError： [Errno 13] Permission denied` error if I put the next image.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

```py
import time
import os
import mimetypes
import base64
import hashlib

from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
from watchdog.observers import Observer

ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES = [
    'image/tiff',
    'image/jpeg',
    'image/png'
]

hashes = {}

class ChangeHandler(FileSystemEventHandler):
    def on_modified(self, event):
        filepath = event.src_path
        filename = os.path.basename(filepath)

        if mimetypes.guess_type(filepath)[0] in ACCEPTED_FILE_TYPES:
            with open(filepath, 'rb') as f: # PermissionError occurs here
                b64_data = base64.b64encode(f.read())
                checksum = hashlib.md5(b64_data).hexdigest()

            if filename not in hashes or (hashes[filename] != checksum):
                hashes[filename] = checksum
                print('%s modified' % filename)
            else:
                pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    event_handler = ChangeHandler()
    observer = Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, './tmp')
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    finally:
        observer.join()
        print('shutting down...')
```

Comment: Could you show us an example of `filepath` and `filename` ?

Comment: `filepath` is something like `./tmp/puppy.jpg` and `filename` would be `puppy.jpg`.

Comment: I can't help you much here, but perhaps check that the filepaths and filenames are always correct until the error? This is along that thought https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207450/permissionerror-errno-13-in-python